# What the array().join() does in the following code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

```
 var object = {
      mastermind : "Brain",
      henchman: "Pinky",
      battleCry: function (noOfBrains) {
        return "They are " + this.henchman + " and the" +
                 Array(noOfBrains + 1).join(" " + this.mastermind);
  }
};

var battleCry = object.battleCry(4);
```

--

Can you explain why **array().join()** *return*:

- *Correct*: "They are Pinky and the Brain Brain Brain Brain"
- *Incorrect*: "They are Pinky and the 5 Brain"

Comment: Because the 5-item `Array` is joined with `" Brain"`.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer a bit more? Also, it is clear that 'this.mastermind' is pointing to "Brain".

Comment: "what does this code do" seems off the topic for me. Specially when all you have to do is running the code. This is not going to help anyone.

Comment: @derloopkat The question clearly ask for : "what **array().join()** does in the following code?" and not "what does this code do".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array().join()` is used to join all the elements of an array together in one string. Optionally, you can specify a delimiter to separate the elements.

In your code, `Array(noOfBrains + 1)` creates a new array with the given length, in your example 4 + 1 = 5 items, but all those 5 items are empty because your code doesn't assign anything to them. So your code is joining 5 empty strings using " Brain" as delimiter. Essentially, this function is actually a repeater of any string assigned to the `mastermind` property for as many times as you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

This creates an array of a given length with undefined elements.  In this example length of 5.  When 5 elements are joined together there are 4 delimiters and each is delimiter is " Brain"

```js
var dummyArray = Array(5);

console.log("Our Dummy Array");
console.log(dummyArray);
console.log();

console.log("Our Dummy Array Joined More Conventially");
console.log(dummyArray.join(","));
console.log();

console.log("Our Dummy Array Joined More Brainly");
console.log(dummyArray.join(" Brain"));
console.log();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in `Array(noOfBrains + 1).join(" " + this.mastermind)` 
 `this.mastermind`  contains the string "**Brain**". 
and `noOfBrains` is '4'. 
 so it becomes  `Array(4+1).join(" " +"Brain")` into `Array(5).join(" Brain")` will show the output as `Brain Brain Brain Brain`

Answer (score 0):

Array join joins all elements of array to string using some string glue.

```
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
console.log(a.join(', '));
```

You will see "one, two, three" in the console.

In your case glue is " Brain". Array is [5] - i mean array with one element which is 5 (4 + 1 = 5). So, [5].join(' Brain') = "5"

If you need repeat some string 2 or more times, you can use String.repeat(times).

In your case:

```
var bcObject = {
    mastermind : "Brain",
    henchman: "Pinky",
    battleCry: function (noOfBrains) {
        return "They are " + this.henchman + " and the" +
            (' ' + this.mastermind).repeat(noOfBrains);
    }
};

var battleCry = bcObject.battleCry(4);
```